# Why do I get this "not an array reference" with Perl XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

My input xml file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<warnings>
 <IDA>
  <file>filea</file>
  <path>patha</path>
 </IDA>

 <IDA>
  <file>fileaa</file>
  <path>pathaa</path>
 </IDA>

 <IDB>
  <file>fileb</file>
  <path>pathb</path>
 </IDB>

</warnings>
```

I am reading this file like this:

```
my @IDs = ("IDA", "IDB");
my $data = $xml->XMLin("xmlfile.xml");
foreach (@IDs)
{
 foreach $id (@{$data->{$_}})
 {
   print $id->{path}."\n";
 }
}
```

and when I run the script it gives me this error:

```
Not an ARRAY reference at ./waiver.pl line 18.
```

(line 18 is the second foreach loop)

**EDIT**
i have duplicated IDA tag.

Comment: Have you tried perl -d mode?  'n' to line 18, then 'x' things like `$_`, `$data->{$_}`, etc.

Comment: sorry i didn't get it? could you please explain a bit?

Comment: He means using Perl debugger with -d option

Comment: Because you're using XML::Simple, the hardest XML parser to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{$data->{$_}` is not a valid array reference because you have only one IDA tag, thus no array is built. You can use `ForceArray` in XMLin to force every tag to be an array even if there's only one.

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("xmlfile.xml", ForceArray => 1);
```

**EDIT**: now it's giving the error with IDB tag...

Alternatively you can use `ref()` to check if it's an array or a hash reference:

```
if (ref({$data->{$_}) eq 'ARRAY')
{
    foreach $id (@{$data->{$_}})
    {
        etc...
    }
}
```

PS: also may I suggest using `keys()` function to retreive the keys of the hash instead of having them in a separate array.

Comment: I already told you how to handle it, but here's another option.

Comment: I typically suggest everyone use `ForceArray`, anyway you cut it returning two distinct types of variables is a tremendous burden on the end user. This actually bothers the hell out of me in many libraries (like DBIC).